# Increment Model Field Inside Get Or Create Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am developing a music web application where I am trying to calculate the number of times a song was played. When the play button is clicked, a function called `getLink()` is called. Here, I try to use `get_or_create` to update the `PlayCount` model, like so.

```
h = PlayCount.objects.all()

    if len(h) == 0:
        u = PlayCount.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user.username,
            song=song,
            plays=1,
        )[0]
        u.save()

    else:

        flag = False

        for i in h:
            if i.song == song:
                u = PlayCount.objects.get_or_create(
                    user=request.user.username,
                    song=song,
                    plays=plays + 1,
                )[0]
                u.save()
                flag = True
                break
            else:
                pass

        if flag is False:
            u = PlayCount.objects.get_or_create(
                user=request.user.username,
                song=song,
                plays=1,
            )[0]
            u.save()
        else:
            pass
```

However, when I enter the else loop, `127.0.0.1:8000` returns `play is not defined`.

How may I proceed?

Comment: You're getting the `plays is not defined` because in your `get_or_create`, you have `plays=plays + 1`, and `plays` isn't defined. FYI, `get_or_create` will always save the object if the object doesn't exist. There's no need to call `u.save()` after using `get_or_create`, unless you plan to modify the instance's attributes after getting/creating.

Comment: So what's the best way to do what I need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you loop through all the `PlayCount` objects when all you need is to find the one for the specific `user` and `song`.

Note also that `get_or_create` will only find the specific object that matches **all** the parameters you pass to it, so `get_or_create(user=..., song=..., plays=...)` will try finding the one with the exact number of plays you specify which isn't what you want.

You only need to do this:

```
from django.db.models import F

play_counter, created = PlayCount.objects.get_or_create(
    user=request.user,
    song=song,
    defaults={'plays': 1})
if not created:
    play_counter.plays = F('plays') + 1
    play_counter.save()
```

So here we first fetch or create the counter for the particular song and user. If we create it, we set `plays` to 1 by setting it in the `defaults` parameter.

Then, if it is not created (i.e. it's an existing one), we increment `plays` by 1, using the `F` expression, which ensures it's updated in the database directly (and there's no risk of database inconsistency due if another request is updating the same value).